# What if someone deletes their question that I already answered?

Tags: support

if a someone's question that I answered is deleted by them, my rewards get removed too?

Comment: They cannot delete their question if your answer has a positive score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if your answer is accepted or upvoted it can't be deleted other than by moderators, If it is deleted then you will lose rep gain by votes.

Quoting [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> You can’t delete your own question when it:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has an accepted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)

There is an exception too.

> Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and
> acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question)
> are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of
> three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for
> at least 60 days, is retained).

Comment: So the rep changes are erased from my history too?

Comment: Most probably you will get notified in form of -10/20 with the name of post.